# Get custom field ACF from taxonomy CPT UI

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

With CPT UI plugin, I created a taxonomy called "Locations".

After that, with ACF Pro, I created a field called "url_location" for each taxonomy Locations.

On my page, here is my code :

```
// Get and reorder each locations V2
   $terms3 = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'locations' );
   $locations_list_v2 = array();
   foreach ( $terms3 as $term3 ) {
      $locations_list_v2[] = '<a href="#">'.$term3->name.'</a> test : ' . get_field('url_location');
   }
    $locations_v2 = join( ", ", $locations_list_v2 );
```

But I can't retrieve my field "url_location", I tried some different codes but nothing works... Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What other codes have you tried? I think you need to add the term id when using get_field like `get_field('url_location', $term3->id);`

Comment: My edit was deleted in original post... I finally found a solution yesterday, here it is : ```get_field('url_location', $term3->taxonomy . '_' . $term3->term_id)``` Thank you Rank :)